# Rplace emoticons from a String,to String using java

Tags: java, emoticons

How to Remove the Emoticons from the String  My simple code is..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    String str="My nam is  ur -D ";
    getRefineCode(str);
}

private static void getRefineCode(String str) throws {
    List smstypeWord=getshortWord();
    for(int i=0;i<smstypeWord.size();i++) {
        String string=smstypeWord.get(i).toString();
        String stringcon[]=string.split("_");
        String emessage=stringcon[0];
        String emoticon=stringcon[1].trim();
        if(str.contains(emoticon)) {
            str=str.replace(emoticon, emessage);
            System.out.println("=================>"+str);
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("=======++==========>"+str);
}

private static List getshortWord() throws SQLException {
    String query1 = "SELECT * FROM englishSmsText";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    String f_message="";
    String s_message="";
    while(rs.next()) {
        s_message=rs.getString("message");
        f_message=rs.getString("short_text");
        shortMessage.add(s_message+"_"+f_message);
        //fullMessage.add(f_message);
    }
    return shortMessage;
}
```

My database is based on http://smsdictionary.co.uk/abbreviations site

I able to understand how to remove the multiple abb. or short message

output is like My nam is  You are SquintLaughtGrinisappGaspoooh!!shockedintedr, Big SmilGrinisappGaspoooh!!shockedinted, Grin

Comment: You should probably be using `replaceAll` rather than `replace`. I can't see anything obvious apart from that, what is the observed vs desired behavior? Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Is there some attempt in the snippet to solve your own problem, or does the code snippet amount to "please complete"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `replace` should be `replaceAll`, otherwise you will only catch the first occurrence of an emoticon or abbreviation.

Second, you can reduce the number of false positives by matching only whole words. `replaceAll` accepts regular expressions, so you can use `replaceAll("\\b" + emoticon + "\\b", emessage)` to only replace abbreviations which are surrounded by word boundaries (whitespace, punctuation etc.).

However, with the dictionary you are using you will still replace `KISS` with `Keep It Simple, Stupid`. You will replace `86` with `"out Of" Or "over" Or "to Get Rid Of"`... Maybe you should be looking for a different approach.

Edit: I forgot you were looking for special characters. You should try something like this regex, which will suppress special characters in the search string (and will be more generous than the previously too-strict `\b` pattern):

```
replaceAll("((?<=\\W)|^)\\Q" + emoticon + "\\E((?=\\W)|$)", emessage);
```

It should cover *most* cases, I doubt there is any way to perfectly identify what is intended as an acronym and what is not.

Comment: but when string contains 'B-)' regular expression error

Comment: what is meaning by ((?<=\\W)|^)\\Q and \\E((?=\\W)|$)

Comment: `((?<=\\W)|^)` means that the match has to either start at the beginning of the input or be preceded by a non-word character such as whitespace or punctuation. `\\Q` prevents characters like `(` in the input from being parsed as if they had special meaning, `\\E` starts parsing again, `((?=\\W)|$)` means that the match has to end at the end of input or be followed by a non-word character.